# How do I get specific object data from using Chef REST API?

Tags: rest, chef-infra

I am trying to get some specific JSON object data from Chef's REST API. I can run curl using the headers and auth headers, along with the path.

I receive JSON data from a GET request to:

```
[chef_server_url]/organizations/[org_name]/nodes/[hostname]
```

and it spits out a lot of useful data that I'm interested in.

Converted to yaml (for easier reading), the results looks similar to this:

```
automatic: 
  chef_packages:
    ...
  cookbooks:
    default:
      version: 1.0.0
    ...
  cpu:
    ...
```

But if I try to perform a GET request to:

```
[chef_server_url]/organizations/[org_name]/nodes/[hostname]/cookbooks/
```

or

```
[chef_server_url]/organizations/[org_name]/nodes/[hostname/automatic/cookbooks
```

etc, I get a 404 error.

How can I get the version value from 'default' cookbooks (or any embedded JSON value) using the REST query?

Answer (score 0):

I mean the only thing (mostly) under `/nodes` would be nodes. Cookbooks live under `/cookbooks/<name>/<version>`. More details are available at https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html.

Comment: I did go through the documentation, but couldn't find what I was looking for, so not sure if it's possible. I'm interested in getting some values from the hostname level itself, which is why I thought it might make sense if it was embedded within /nodes/[hostname]/[values]. ex. I only want the cookbooks, or cpu details, (or anything other key value results that are provided within /nodes[hostname]) about a particular /nodes/[hostname], but not /cookbooks/name as it doesn't reflect which cookbooks are installed on [hostname]. I hope that makes as much sense as it does in my head.:)

Comment: I think you mean you want node attributes, which you have to parse from the main node object.

Comment: How would you parse those node attributes? Would I need to do it programmatically using something like Python to parse the JSON output, or can I grab the node attribute value directly from a key using only the Chef REST API?

Comment: You have to parse the JSON. Our API is based around JSON documents just in general.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying. That's the answer I was looking for.